# PHP shell_exec touch file permission issue running as sudo

Tags: php, ubuntu, sudo

I want to create a file in PHP using `shell_exec`. Here's the statement I'm trying:

```
$out = shell_exec('sudo touch maintenance.flag 2>&1 1> /dev/null');
```

And contents of `$out` are

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, so I `visudo` to take a look at the sudo permissions. I set sudo to:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but it's still not working. What are some things or alternatives I can try to resolve this?

Comment: Boy this seems like a very bad idea. Why not just create a path within your app that is writable instead?

Comment: Yeah, that was another idea too. Explain *why* this is a bad idea though please.

Comment: It creates an attack vector which isn't needed to solve the problem at hand. You don't need root, so don't open that possibility. Scripts being able to escalate so easily can compromise your server.  You may think, my script is secure, and maybe it is, but what about everything else on the server?